# Cache player with GameSparks and Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to gamesparks, but so far I have set up a login/register function, which works like it should, but... How do I ensure that the user don't have to login next time he or she opens the app?

I found [this](http://www.gamesparks.com/blog/unity-and-gamesparks/) in which I read that I can just run this:

```
GameSparkssApi.isAuthenticated().
```

First off all, in all other tutorials it states that it should be: `GameSparks.Api.xxxx`. Even when trying this I do not find `isAuthenticated()` anywhere.

```
GameSparks.Api.isAuthenticated();
```

I am hoping that someone can cast some light on this.

Comment: Oh, you could just use Parse.com ... hahahah  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Device Authentication for this purpose. This method of auth sets an access token for the device you are on. This token is stored and the client and gotten in the request. these requests are structured like so:

```
 new GameSparks.Api.Requests.DeviceAuthenticationRequest()
.SetDeviceId(deviceId)
.SetDeviceModel(deviceModel)
.SetDeviceName(deviceName)
.SetDeviceOS(deviceOS)
.SetDeviceType(deviceType)
.SetDisplayName(displayName)
.SetOperatingSystem(operatingSystem)
.SetSegments(segments)
.Send((response) => {
    string authToken = response.AuthToken;
    string displayName = response.DisplayName;
    bool? newPlayer = response.NewPlayer;
    GSData scriptData = response.ScriptData;
    var switchSummary = response.SwitchSummary;
    string userId = response.UserId;
});
```

You can find more on this method in our documentation: https://api.gamesparks.net/#deviceauthenticationrequest

Regards Patrick, GameSparks.